# Value Iteration

Tags: reinforcement-learning

For value iteration problem, using Bellman equation for iteration 2 , it is clear to me how values are getting calculated.

[image]

But for iteration 3 values are unclear to me. Can one help me in this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

welcome to datascience stackexchange. In an iteration 3 let's take a look that for <3,3> you can take exactly the same formula to get these new values. In an iteration (2) you had in a central part of your equation 0.1 [0+0.9 * 0], because value function of this state was 0. In an iteration (3) you have value function equal to 0.72, so the formula would change to 0.1 [0+0.9 * 0.72] and it added to the rest of expression will efect in 0.78 (rounded two second digit after decimal).

Let's trace it down for state <2,3> using exactly the same formula. We should go up (because of highest value function amongst neighbours), so I guess level of obedience will be 0.8 and there also will be 0.1 probability of going right. So, we can calculate the new value function for this state as:
0.8 [0 + 0.9 * 0.72] + 0.1 [0 + 0.9 * (-1)] = 0.4284 = 0.43